# Changing AlfrescoDocument properties doesn't have any effect

Tags: java, metadata, alfresco, alfresco-share, opencmis

Recently I'm working on adding metadata to file in Alfresco repository. I'm using following code:

```
    AlfrescoDocument alfDoc = (AlfrescoDocument) doc;
    Map<String, Object> aspectProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    aspectProperties.put("cm:description", "test1");
    alfDoc.removeAspect("P:cm:titled");
    alfDoc.addAspect("P:cm:titled", aspectProperties);
    System.out.println(alfDoc.getProperties());
```

I can't get this one to work. It's possible to clear title with this one, but I can't just set one - description is blank. What am I doing wrong?

My libraries:

- alfresco-opencmis-extension-1.0
- chemistry-opencmis-client-0.13.0
- chemistry-opencmis-commons-0.13.0

I'm using scraps of this java class:

http://svn.codespot.com/a/apache-extras.org/alfresco-opencmis-extension/trunk/src/test/org/alfresco/cmis/client/test/CMISClientTest.java

Comment: Why are you removing then re-adding the aspect? Why not just set the properties directly?

Comment: Which end point are you using (what is your service URL)? It matters because if you are using CMIS 1.1 you should not use the OpenCMIS Extension.

Comment: Ow. That may be the case. I'm using following url: "alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom". Could you give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the updateProperties method as shown [here](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/pra/1/concepts/opencmis-ext-adding.html) if using Alfresco OpenCMIS extension
OR if using Apache OpenCMIS then [this](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.13.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/CmisObject.html#updateProperties(java.util.Map))

Unitl you don't explicitly call the updateProperties method it will not commit those changes on the repository side.

Comment: I tried updateProperties method but it seems to work, until I manually change properties using Alfresco share interface.

Comment: Here is example: 1. upload file to repository 2. set property using "cmis:description" and updateProperties 3. result is visible in alfresco 4. i manually change value in share interface 5. running the same code this time does nothing - no effect on file properties, no error displayed.